# integrating multiplication of complex functions

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, complex-integration, quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

In my calculations on a problem of quantum optics, I faced an integral of the following form
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\pi}\int e^{(\beta^*  \alpha)} f(\alpha^*)  d^2 \alpha
\end{align}
with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ complex values. May anyone help me with this problem please?

(I know that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\pi}\int e^{(\beta^*  \alpha)-|\alpha|^2} f(\alpha^*)  d^2 \alpha= f(\beta^*)
\end{align}

(Note: The exact form of $f(\alpha)$ is $E_h (|w|^2 - \alpha ^*)$ that $E_h$ is an $h$ deformed exponential and $w$ is constant value. ))

Comment: What is an deformed exponential? It is not clear that the integral even converges to me.

Comment: It is exponential, with a power series expansion. We can take it $e^{(|w|^2 - \alpha^*)}$.

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456403/area-integral-over-complex-plane-of-non-holomorphic-gaussian-e-z-barz).

Comment: Des your deformed exponential, whatever it is, have a simple pole?

Comment: No, it does not have a simple pole.

Comment: Your "i know that" integral does, $f(\alpha^*)/(\beta^*-\alpha^*)$, so you used Cauchy's theorem. But, then, if no pole, the integral is zero, no?